Power BI to compare two datasets
Here is a sample of my CSV file:
testName,timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,Hostname,Connect
Release_1,1.71E+12,120,BlazeMeter Homepage#1,200,OK,Thread Group#1 1-2,TRUE,226529,4,8,97,2cea3485d134,88
Release_1,1.71E+12,116,BlazeMeter Homepage#3,200,OK,Thread Group#2 2-2,TRUE,226529,4,8,97,2cea3485d134,87
Release_1,1.71E+12,345,BlazeMeter Homepage#3,200,OK,Thread Group#2 2-1,TRUE,226529,4,8,266,2cea3485d134,249
Release_1,1.71E+12,354,BlazeMeter Homepage#1,200,OK,Thread Group#1 1-1,TRUE,226530,4,8,277,2cea3485d134,261
Release_1,1.71E+12,33,BlazeMeter Homepage#1,200,OK,Thread Group#1 1-3,TRUE,226529,4,8,24,2cea3485d134,14
Release_2,1.71E+12,120,BlazeMeter Homepage#1,200,OK,Thread Group#1 1-2,TRUE,226529,4,8,234,2cea3485d134,88
Release_2,1.71E+12,116,BlazeMeter Homepage#3,200,OK,Thread Group#2 2-2,TRUE,226529,4,8,432,2cea3485d134,87
Release_2,1.71E+12,345,BlazeMeter Homepage#3,200,OK,Thread Group#2 2-1,TRUE,226529,4,8,656,2cea3485d134,249
Release_2,1.71E+12,354,BlazeMeter Homepage#1,200,OK,Thread Group#1 1-1,TRUE,226530,4,8,455,2cea3485d134,261
Release_2,1.71E+12,33,BlazeMeter Homepage#1,200,OK,Thread Group#1 1-3,TRUE,226529,4,8,434,2cea3485d134,14
Now, I would like to compare the "elapsed" time of labels between Release_1 and Release_2. To achieve this, I have created a new table.
ComparisonTable = 
UNION(
 SELECTCOLUMNS(
 FILTER('performance_two_reports 3', 'performance_two_reports 3'[testName] = "Release_1"),
 "Label", 'performance_two_reports 3'[label],
 "Release_1_Time", 'performance_two_reports 3'[elapsed]
    ),
 SELECTCOLUMNS(
 FILTER('performance_two_reports 3', 'performance_two_reports 3'[testName] = "Release_2"),
 "Label", 'performance_two_reports 3'[label],
 "Release_2_Time",'performance_two_reports 3'[elapsed]
    )
)

But, my new table has only two columns instead of 3. Why "Release_2_Time" column is not shown in the ComparisonTable? Thanks
